# Installing PThread on linux for tophat

Tags: linux, pthreads, installation

[Bowtie](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) is a program which is needed for tophat. I need this program to map a few hundredmilion reads against  a reference genome. Bowtie does the mapping part, this needs many CPU. In the manual of bowtie there is an option to do this multithreaded, but the library PThread needs to be installed.

I downloaded PThread from [this website](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~bterwijn/Projects/PThread/). Extracted this to my program folder, opened a shell and was standing in this directory. When entering the command 'make', I get this error and I don't know how to solve this.

---

> if /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CXX --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.  -Wall    -g -O2 -MT PThreadRun.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/PThreadRun.Tpo" -c -o PThreadRun.lo PThreadRun.cpp; \
>
> then mv -f ".deps/PThreadRun.Tpo" ".deps/PThreadRun.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/PThreadRun.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
>
> g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -Wall -g -O2 -MT PThreadRun.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/PThreadRun.Tpo -c PThreadRun.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/PThreadRun.o
>   PThreadRun.cpp: In member function 'pthread_t PThreadRun::start()':
>
> PThreadRun.cpp:28:38: error: 'redirectPthreadRun' was not declared in this scope
>
> make: *** [PThreadRun.lo] Error 1
>
> make: Leaving directory `/install_dir'
>
> make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make: Leaving directory `/install_dir'
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

---

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: According to http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/manual.shtml#building-from-source it needs the "pthreads" library, which I'm 95% sure means the pthreads library which is probably already installed on your machine, rather than the "PThread" library you link to, which seems to be some C++ wrapper around pthreads.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run configure first. Per the installation instructions:

> These are generic installation instructions.
>
> The `configure' shell script attempts to guess correct values for
>   various system-dependent variables used during compilation.  It uses
>   those values to create a`Makefile' in each directory of the package.
>   It may also create one or more `.h' files containing system-dependent
>   definitions.  Finally, it creates a shell script`config.status' that
>   you can run in the future to recreate the current configuration, and a
>   file `config.log' containing compiler output (useful mainly for
>   debugging`configure').
>
> It can also use an optional file (typically called `config.cache'
>   and enabled with`--cache-file=config.cache' or simply `-C') that
>   saves the results of its tests to speed up reconfiguring.  (Caching is
>   disabled by default to prevent problems with accidental use of stale
>   cache files.)
>
> If you need to do unusual things to compile the package, please try
>   to figure out how `configure' could check whether to do them, and mail
>   diffs or instructions to the address given in the`README' so they can
>   be considered for the next release.  If you are using the cache, and
>   at some point `config.cache' contains results you don't want to keep,
>   you may remove or edit it.
>
> The file `configure.ac' (or`configure.in') is used to create
>   `configure' by a program called`autoconf'.  You only need
>   `configure.ac' if you want to change it or regenerate`configure'
>   using a newer version of `autoconf'.
>
> The simplest way to compile this package is:
>
> 1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type`
>      ./configure' to configure the package for your system.  If you're
>       using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might need to type`
>      sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying to execute`
>      configure' itself.
>
>    Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
>       messages telling which features it is checking for.
> 2. Type `make' to compile the package.
> 3. Optionally, type `make check' to run any self-tests that come with
>       the package.
> 4. Type `make install' to install the programs and any data files and
>       documentation.
> 5. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
>       source code directory by typing `make clean'.  To also remove the
>       files that`configure' created (so you can compile the package for
>       a different kind of computer), type `make distclean'.  There is
>       also a`make maintainer-clean' target, but that is intended mainly
>       for the package's developers.  If you use it, you may have to get
>       all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
>       with the distribution.

Comment: I ran the ./configure (did it before too, but did forget to tell... In this log file, there are some errors, like conftest.cc:25:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory

Comment: If you are getting an error when running configure, then this is a problem with the distribution. You need to contact the vendor. If you can't get configure to work, then make most definitely won't.